# Remove all characters between two substrings in Hive SQL query

Tags: hive, hiveql, regexp-replace

I have a column of strings that looks like this:

STRING:SECTION1/SECTION2/0000123456789/SECTION3/SECTION4
STRING:SECTION1/SECTION2/0000987654321/SECTION3/SECTION4
STRING:SECTION1/SECTION2/00005552121X/SECTION3/SECTION4
STRING:SECTION1/SECTION2/00005552222:ID/SECTION3/SECTION4

I am trying to use REGEXP_REPLACE to replace the variable length, alpha/num/special char string from the middle and replace it with something generic so that they all look like this:

STRING:SECTION1/SECTION2/id_number_removed/SECTION3/SECTION4

I have been trying all morning to try to find the right regex expression to replace everything between '/SECTION2/' and '/SECTION3/' but have had no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace regex pattern `'SECTION2/[^/]+/SECTION3'` with `'SECTION2/id_number_removed/SECTION3'`. `[^/]+` means 1 or more characters that are not slashes.

```
select regexp_replace(
    'STRING:SECTION1/SECTION2/00005552222:ID/SECTION3/SECTION4',
    'SECTION2/[^/]+/SECTION3', 
    'SECTION2/id_number_removed/SECTION3');
```

which gives

```
STRING:SECTION1/SECTION2/id_number_removed/SECTION3/SECTION4
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.